# Anything like Regular expressions

Tags: objective-c

Is there something similar to regular expressions for objective-c?

I need a simple way to get elements from separated by following set of characters:

```
"\n"
", "
"; "
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *translations = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *temp_array1 = [ [translationsView text] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for (int i = 0; i < [temp_array1 count]; i++)
{
    NSArray *temp_array2 = [ [temp_array1 objectAtIndex: i] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    for (int j = 0; j < [temp_array2 count]; j++)
    {j]);
        [translations addObject: [temp_array2 objectAtIndex: j] ];
    }
}
```

But I as well want implement support for the "; " separator. And if I am going to do it the same way I did it before it would become way to complex.

Is there an easier way to achieve this goal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will want to look at [RegexKit Framework](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/).

> RegexKit is an Objective-C framework
>   for regular expressions:
>
> - Support for Mac OS X Cocoa and GNUstep. Mac OS X 10.4 or later
>     required.
> - Mac OS X Universal Binary, including 64-bit support on Mac OS X 10.5.
> - No sub-classing required. Seamlessly adds regular expression support to all
>     NSArray, NSData, NSDictionary, NSSet,
>     and NSString Foundation objects with a
>     rich set of Objective-C category
>     additions.
> - Unicode enabled. Full Unicode support for NSString objects.
> - Extensive, high quality documentation.
> - Full source code with a BSD license.
> - Uses the BSD licensed PCRE Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library
>     for the regular expression engine.
>
> Tuned for high performance, including
>   such features as:
>
> - Caches the compiled form of the regular expression for speed.
> - Multithreading safe, including multiple reader, single writer
>     multithreaded access to the compiled
>     regular expression cache.
> - Makes minimal use of heap storage (ie, malloc() and free()), instead
>     allocating most temporary buffer needs
>     dynamically from the stack.
> - Uses Core Foundation directly on Mac OS X for additional speed.
>
> Includes support for Mac OS X 10.5
>   Leopard:
>
> - 64 bit support. Pre-built for ppc, ppc64, i386, and x86_64.
> - Garbage Collection enabled. Complete support for Leopards Garbage
>     Collection feature.
> - Integrated Xcode 3.0 documentation. Get real time API information via the
>     Research Assistant.
> - Collection of instruments for Instruments.app.
> - RegexKit specific DTrace probe points.